# "Scaffolding" or "A scaffolding"?

Tags: grammar

Is it more correct to say:

> "There is a scaffolding around my house"

than:

> "There is scaffolding around my house" ?

Answer (score 2):

Scaffolding is more correctly used as non-count noun.  So therefore, "There is  scaffolding around the house" is the correct answer.

Comment: The idea is whether scaffolding is a count or non-count noun.  I would argue it is more correct as non-count noun.  A non-count noun is like furniture.   You never pluralize furniture.  A count noun is more common. It is like boy.  It can be pluralized.  I could never imagine saying Scaffolding**S**

Comment: ab2 quotes examples of it used as a count noun, from a dictionary. On what grounds do you assert that a non-count noun is "more correct"?(Myself, I have never heard it as a count noun, but clearly others disagree).

Comment: Only personal experience.  I do agree that "a scaffolding" doesn't sound completely incorrect, but rather strange.  "Scaffolding**s**" sounds bizarre and like a foreign language learner that is using the language.  I guess we need to go to a dictionary to be sure.

Comment: Okay, I found this reference in Wiktionary that backs up my point as being more correct.  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scaffolding#English  They refer to scaffolding as "Usually noncount", but make a reference to scaffoldings.  I completely agree with this.  Though it is Wiktionary...

Comment: So it can be used as a count noun too.. For example,  if I say:"what is this?"  I guess " It's a scaffolding" sounds more correct than "It's scaffolding".

Comment: Yes, it would seem so, but only in my humble personal opinion, grinds more on my ears than just "It's scaffolding."

Comment: To me, the mass noun is "scaffolding", so I don't use it with "a" or in the plural.  The count noun is "a scaffold"; in other words, a particular instance of scaffolding.  I can use "scaffold" in the plural as well to tell how many there are around buildings on, say, on one block.

Answer (score 2):

To my surprise, you can say either.  To my ear, "scaffolding around the house" sounds more natural, but "a scaffolding around the house" is also OK.

Examples: [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scaffolding).  I am giving two examples of "a scaffolding" followed by two examples of "scaffolding"

> Her father, who was a mason, was killed by falling from a scaffolding
>
> We saw a tall wooden scaffolding on the very peak of the summit, a 
>   hundred yards away, and made for it.
>
> I had a dim impression of scaffolding, but I was already going too
>   fast to be conscious of any moving things
>
> Some scaffolding had been erected against the end wall, and the stone-work had been broken into, but there were no signs of any workmen at the moment of our visit

Comment: Thank you, reading the examples above was helpful! I wrote this sentence to a friend: "the house is covered with a scaffolding" and he corrected me writing " the house is covered with scaffolding". Maybe "the house is covered by a scaffolding" is more appropriate..?

Comment: @Dani  "The house is covered by scaffolding" sounds more natural to me, and it is more commonly used.  However, what you wrote is not incorrect, just unusual.

Comment: Thank you ab2, there are definitely non-native speaker features in my English, although I like to speak it as correctly as possible..